# IOS: Moving file to directory

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I have this code and error with text:

> ERROR: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x145b5a60 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E905FE5A-C39B-41F0-8BC7-FC58CC3F4306/Library/Caches/2D0404EE-746C-4C1E-98F3-42FFE485BE3B.zip, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move
>   ), NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E905FE5A-C39B-41F0-8BC7-FC58CC3F4306/Library/Caches/2D0404EE-746C-4C1E-98F3-42FFE485BE3B.zip, NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E905FE5A-C39B-41F0-8BC7-FC58CC3F4306/Documents/Files/temp.zip, NSUnderlyingError=0x1457af70 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *pathDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dictionaryName = @"Files";
NSString *filesPath = [[pathDocumentDirectory objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dictionaryName];
NSString *toPath = [filesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.zip"];
NSString *fromPath = downloadedItem.contentURL.path;
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL isDir = YES;

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fromPath])
{
    // Create PurchasedBooks directory
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dictionaryName isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dictionaryName withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]moveItemAtPath:fromPath toPath:toPath error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.description);
    }
}
```

Really do not understand why this happens

Comment: The line `[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dictionaryName withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];` is useless because `"Files"` is not a file path. Also, have you tried logging the value of `fromPath` before the operation?

Answer (score 0):

Add error checking for:

```
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dictionaryName withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: ERROR: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x165ec390 {NSFilePath=Files, NSUnderlyingError=0x165ea2d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}

Comment: You need to provide the full path of the folder you want to create as the parameter. @"Files" doesn't seem to be a valid path.

Comment: Replace dictionaryName with filesPath for createDirectoryAtPath.